# Get the last tick for a chart axis

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I've calculated a stepsize for an axis on a chart.

Also I have the Min and Max -Values.

Until now I'm getting the first step like:

```
            if (xValue >= 0)
            {
                this.myXValues.Add((((int)(xValue / stepSize)) * stepSize));
            }
            else
            {
                this.myXValues.Add((((int)((xValue - stepSize + 1) / stepSize)) * stepSize));
            }
```

Now my question is how to figure out what the last step is. 
I need a algorithm like the one for the first step.

Edit: Example:

*Given Values:*

Max: 320

Stepsize: 100

*Expected outcome:* 400

*Given Values:*

Max: -470

Stepsize: 50

*Expected outcome:* -450

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the last tick you just have to modify code a bit:

```
 if (xValue >= 0)
        {
            this.myXValues.Add((((int)((xValue + stepSize - 1) / stepSize)) * stepSize));
        }
        else
        {
            this.myXValues.Add((((int)(xValue / stepSize)) * stepSize));
        }
```

Comment: Which value needs to be rounded up?

Comment: Integer division (with optional addend) is equivalent to rounding of ratio `value/stepsize`  to minus infinity of to plus infinity.  (here `10/3 => 4`)

Comment: but e.g. (((640 + 100 - 1) / 100)) * 100 = 800 but i expected 700

Comment: oh i think where you wrote + should be -

Comment: No, this expression gives 700. How did you get 800?

Comment: 1. Math.Ceiling((640 + 100 - 1)/100)=8
2. 8*100 = 800

Comment: Integer division with `+ 100 - 1` already performs ceiling to 7, you don't need to make it explicitly. I changed answer to ready-to-use code

Answer (score 0):

This is how to obtain numbers between min and max, by respecting the stepsize:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetTicksBetweenNumbersBySteps(1000, 213, 4405)));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", GetTicksBetweenNumbersBySteps(500, -1213, 1405)));
    }

    private static List<int> GetTicksBetweenNumbersBySteps(int stepsize, int min, int max)
    {
        List<int> foundTicks = new List<int>() { 0 };

        int actualTick = 0;

        while (actualTick > min)
        {
            actualTick -= stepsize;

            if (actualTick >= min)
            {
                foundTicks.Add(actualTick);
            }
        }

        actualTick = 0;

        while (actualTick < max)
        {
            actualTick += stepsize;

            if (actualTick <= max)
            {
                foundTicks.Add(actualTick);
            }
        }

        return foundTicks.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
    }
```

Output:

> 0,1000,2000,3000,4000
>
> -1000,-500,0,500,1000

Comment: Yes but how can i figure out the max value in before?